# PHP not worked in IIS express when wordpress run with no issue

Tags: php, webmatrix, iis-express

I have install WordPress through webmatrix and they are work fine in my computer when I run them. When I create a new website or create from template then it's not worked. Suppose I made a index.page and when I try to run them. I got this message in browser.

HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

Can someone help in this case.Wordpress is running with .php extension means PHP is installed on server like

Now someone can help me how I can resolve this issue.

Regards

Comment: I have found that 3  instance of  C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\PHP\v5.3\php-cgi.exe is running.

Answer (score 6):

IT sounds like you may just need to enable PHP for your site.  If you go to the Site workspace, and click on 'settings', you should see an option for 'Enable PHP'.  Is this checkbox checked?  Also, multiple instances of php-cgi-exe isn't a bad thing, it's just how PHP in IIS works :-)